# What java structure for a binary semaphore

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I have:

- Many threads that produce items
- One single thread that updates the GUI by displaying the items

Key points:

- Producing item is much faster than updating the GUI
- We may have many new items produced simultaneously
- Every item production must be followed by one GUI update
- If productions occur simultaneously, all of them must be followed by **only** one update.. there is no need to refresh GUI more than once

I think I'm looking for some standard structure that implements a binary semaphore, where the maximum number of permits is 1, so that workers can call multiple `release()` without blocking each other, and if a `release()` is called, then:

- If the GUI thread is sleeping => it is woken up
- If the GUI thread is performing its routine instead => it must restart it once it's over, before going to sleep again

Code should look like:

```
[Workers]
.. produce item ..
sem.release()

[GUI Thread]
while(true) {
  sem.acquire()
  .. update gui ..
}
```

Please note that a `Semaphore` initialized with 1 available permit is not a solution to this scenario, because many workers completing their task simultaneously should release only one permit; otherwise GUI thread would run too many times

Comment: What does "simultaneously" mean in "If productions occur simultaneously"?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: @shmosel This is a common scenario: worker procudes an item. Gui starts updating. other 10 workers produce 10 items. Gui finish to update, but must restart its routing one more time (and only one time). Can you please also share a solution with ReadWriteLock

Comment: It’s not clear what “If the GUI thread is performing its routing instead” is supposed to mean. What “routing”? Besides that, are you talking about a real life GUI? Swing for example, has [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) designed for this job. Otherwise, you’re talking about “producing items”, so is neither, one of the [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations nor `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, suitable?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It was "routine" not routing. GUI thread's routine updates JTable lines, JTextFields values, and to draw charts. Each worker produces value into a concurrent list, sometime it's a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, sometime it's a synchronized list. GUI routine will read such values and instruct swing on how to display them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Semaphore?

Producers 'up' the semaphore by 1 for every item produced.

Consumer 'downs' the semaphore by as much as possible; something like this:

```
sema.acquire();  
n = 1;
while (sema.tryAcquire(very short timeout))
    ++n;
// there are now known to be n items available
```

and perhaps the same loop on tryAcquire at the end of GUI 'routing', whatever that is.

That's a little racy. How firm are your requirements on **only** one update?  Can you live with occasionally getting more than one?

If it must be exactly one update only, then there needs to be a two-way interlock (i.e., classic producer-consumer).  Whatever you do without it, you can't stop a producer producing 'just one more item' a few nanoseconds after you've decided you have got them all.  To close that hole, producers need to be told to hold off while the GUI updates.

Comment: Of course it's fine to have occasionally more than one update. This solution solves the problem. Anyway I was wondering if there is some more specific standard class to achieve the same.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - you'll have to roll your own.